# Set design help!

Tags: modeling

I'm currently working on a set design for a television show I'm producing and I am using blender to design the set. However this is my first time and I'm worried that my design wont be good enough for fabricators and builders to work off of. I'm worried they will look at the design and say "cool, but there are no technical specifications."

my question is to anyone who has built something off of an initial mock up. Do I need to learn proper building code or have my mock-up be close to a blueprint or can I just leave that up to the fabricators and builders to figure out?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Since this isn't really about Blender, this question might be closed. You can also try your luck on https://blenderartists.org/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not appear to be about using Blender.